# iPhone iOS 4 Core Data - Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”

Tags: uitableview, core-data, ios, crash

I'm trying to create an app based on Apple's example project TheElements, but using Core Data for the model.  In Core Data I have 4 related DB tables.  In the UI I have several tableViews, each showing rows from a different Db table.  Clicking a row in a tableView drills down to items in a related table, shown in another TableView.

Everything is working but the app crashes unexpectedly at random times with the error: Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.  BTW this error only shows in the console when debugging on the device.  No error shows when debugging on the simulator.  This [screen grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muyGU.png) shows the contents of the debugger after a crash.

I have no idea how to decipher the debugger. All I can see is the crash seems to stem from the main() function and _PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue is also listed, which leads to guess that I'm doing something wrong with Core Data.

To implement Core Data I'm adding the following to my App Delegate header:

```
@private  
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext_;  
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel_;  
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator_;  

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;  
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;  
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator
```

and adding Apple's default methods for these to App Delegate implementation file.

Then to my Data Source Protocol header I've added:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;  
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;`
```

and my Data Source header files are as follows:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>  
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>  
#import "TableViewDataSourceProtocol.h"  

@interface MatchesAllDataSource : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource,TableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>  
{  
 NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;  
 NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;  
}  

@end
```

When a table cell is clicked I pass the selectedObject as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath  
{  
 // deselect the new row using animation  
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:YES];  

 // get the element that is represented by the selected row.  
 Match *selectedMatch = [dataSource objectForIndexPath:newIndexPath];  

 // create an AtomicElementViewController. This controller will display the full size tile for the element  
 MatchViewController *matchController = [[MatchViewController alloc] init];  

 // set the element for the controller  
 matchController.selectedMatch = selectedMatch;  

 // push the element view controller onto the navigation stack to display it  
 [[self navigationController] pushViewController:matchController animated:YES];  
 [matchController release];  
}`
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing my crash?
Will someone please point me in the right direction to look for an answer?
Is there a better way to implement Core Data with multiple tableViews?
Will someone point me to a good example of Core Data with multiple tableViews?

Comment: Your first clue here is the presence of `objc_msgSend` in the stack trace. 99.9% of the time, this indicates that you're sending a message to a deallocated object. Double-check that the relevant objects are being managed correctly. This might help, especially the bit about zombies: http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access/

Comment: I second that and would also add this <http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled> as another helpful resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too with Marcus' code because I changed the UITableViewController to a regular UIViewController and forgot to put in the title.  Here is his original code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
if (self = [super initWithStyle:style]) {
    self.title = @"Australia";
}
return self;
```

}

So if you happened to have changed things make sure that you are setting the self.title somewhere so the custom NSArray+PerformSelector can see it when the app is initializing... like in init.

Answer (score 0):

I had this a few days ago. In my case, I was accessing an object that had already been deallocated.

Comment: Also I can see from the error that the problem is with `title`, but all my views have titles so this doesn't much help me narrow things down :-(

Comment: BTW I am using Marcus Crafter's SegmentedControlExample: http://redartisan.com/2010/6/27/uisegmented-control-view-switching-revisited , which does:    `self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[viewControllers arrayByPerformingSelector:@selector(title)]];` but this is called when initialising the segmented controller and the app tends to crash when going back through the nav, but not always...

Answer (score 0):

Also I passing the managedObjectContext object from view to view as the user navigates down the navigationController views like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath 
{
    matchSegmentedController.selectedMatch = selectedMatch;
    matchSegmentedController.managedObjectContext = dataSource.managedObjectContext;
```